# Error Passing Array Variables into String

Tags: ruby, httparty

This:

```
api_url = [1, 2, 3, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27]
api_url.each do |deal|
  response = HTTParty.get('http://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?filter_id=' + deal.to_s + '&start=0&sort_mode=asc&api_token=example')
  result = JSON.parse(response.body)
end
```

spits out:

```
[1, 2, 3, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27]
```

rather than the resulting JSON it's supposed to. When I replace loop with just one single call rather than an array, this very similar block afterwords works perfectly:

```
stage_deal_ids.each do |deal|
  response = HTTParty.get('http://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/' + deal.to_s + '/activities?start=0&api_token=example')
  result = JSON.parse(response.body)
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `map` not `each`:

```
api_url = [1, 2, 3, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27]
responses = api_url.map do |deal|
  response = HTTParty.get("http://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?filter_id=#{deal}&start=0&sort_mode=asc&api_token=example")
  JSON.parse(response.body)
end
puts responses.inspect
```

`each` just returns the original collection.

Comment: Also it's always better to use string interpolation which calls to_s by default.

Comment: Updated the example for it.